# Really slow call to list all products?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, performance

I'm trying to fetch around 500 products from Magento, but the call is really slow.

```
    $startTime = microtime(TRUE);
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_api')->items();

    $endTime = microtime(TRUE);
    $totalTime = $endTime - $startTime;
    $timePerProduct = $totalTime / count($collection);

    $benchmarking = array(      
        "totaltime" => $totalTime,
        "timeperproduct" => $timePerProduct,
        "totalproducts" => count($collection)           
    );

    $response = array($benchmarking, $collection);
    echo json_encode($response);
```

The total time is ending up being an entire second! I'm not sure if this is normal

`{
    totaltime: 1.0537550449371,
    timeperproduct: 0.0018136919878436,
    totalproducts: 581
},`

I'm currently running the server on Windows Azure A2 configuration. (2 cores, 3.5GB memory. PHP is 5.4, Centos 7.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real question is, do you need to get all that data for products or just a few attributes?

You could specify which attributes you need to speed things up. (as you can also see when opening Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api)
Only there is more data to grab secondhand if you take a closer look, category ids are loaded, etcetera.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
```

To get initial counts you should also use getSize() instead of count() on large collections to speed things up.

```
$collection->getSize();
```

Of coarse you should not be surprised by load times of +1 second on large collections. That's where pagination joins in.

For lazy loading you could start by using setPage (getSize will still return the total amount of products)

```
$pageNum = 1; $pageSize = 25;
$collection->setPage($pageNum, $pageSize);
```

Contents of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api->items($filters = null, $store = null)

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addStoreFilter($this->_getStoreId($store))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name');

/** @var $apiHelper Mage_Api_Helper_Data */
$apiHelper = Mage::helper('api');
$filters = $apiHelper->parseFilters($filters, $this->_filtersMap);
try {
    foreach ($filters as $field => $value) {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $value);
    }
} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    $this->_fault('filters_invalid', $e->getMessage());
}
$result = array();
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $result[] = array(
        'product_id' => $product->getId(),
        'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
        'name'       => $product->getName(),
        'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
        'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
        'category_ids' => $product->getCategoryIds(),
        'website_ids'  => $product->getWebsiteIds()
    );
}
return $result;
```

As you can see, you can just use some best practices in your own controller.

A working example with your code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore())
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name');

// Set page
$collection->setPage(1, 50);

$result = array();
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $result[] = array(
        'product_id' => $product->getId(),
        'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
        'name'       => $product->getName(),
        'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
        'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
        'category_ids' => $product->getCategoryIds(),
        'website_ids'  => $product->getWebsiteIds()
    );
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: The problem is I actually need to add attributes to the ones returning already, rather than take away the default ones returned. (Product ID, SKU, Name, categories, etc..) However, as you said, I think I need to add pagination to speed things up.

Comment: You could apply a sort of lazy loading... Than visually a user gets an initial view, after that you load the rest(if needed), I do not believe the users sees 500+ products in one view(but I could be wrong ;))

Comment: Indeed, that seems to be the only reasonable solution. The problem is I'm still mostly new to Magento, and I'm trying to figure out how to get the products with pagination and lazy. :d

Comment: I've updated my answer with the setPage option

Comment: Excellent! You just saved me a lot of research! I've read up a bit on it, and it seems I have to override/make my own class for the product API, correct?

Comment: I would like to believe you've already created a controller which generates your json, so instead of using the api(take a look at the function app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api.php -> items() ) create your own iterator. (I'll copy the contents of the items() to my answer)

Comment: Yes, I've already done the controller, but currently it's calling the Products Item function which you linked. $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_api')->items();

Comment: One final question, should I override the class and make a new items function, or just change the code in the core?

Comment: Let's pretend I didn't read your last comment! Never change code in the core!

Comment: I was suggesting you should copy/paste the code from items() to your controller, remove a few bits(like the filter) and add the setPage, and use the created array in your json_encode return (ps. I'll update my edit so it will work in you case)

Comment: Thank you a lot! You really helped me clear out a lot of questions going on in my head! I wish I can give you more than juts an accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

Yes Magento IS that slow if you query the product catalogue with that particular API call. The API call will load the complex product model data and make many, many database calls to retrieve the data you requested. The database is an Entity-Attribute-Value database where there is great flexibility but not a lot of speed.

This lack of speed is solved on the front end by using a 'flat catalog'. This is a series of tables in the database where the complex data that is normally held in untold tables is put in simple rows is placed. There is one flat product catalogue table for each store view.

It might take a while to adjust to Magento and its 'slow speed'.

Comment: I currently don't really have a front end, I'm just adding json responses for my app when it asks for products and such. Unless of course that qualifies as front end as well!

Comment: I tried enabling the flat catalog for products, and it seemed to mess things up for me. Only half the products were being returned, and their skus were being returned as null..